# Return ActionResult OR Task from function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core-webapi

The following code is used to check a user's authentication status. If the user is authenticated, it redirects to front end endpoint, which is a synchronous `RedirectResult`. If the user is not, it needs to call the `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync` function, which returns a `Task`.

```cs
public async Task<dynamic> Authorize()
{
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return Redirect("/authorize");
    }

    return await ChallengeAsync();
}

public async Task<dynamic> ChallengeAsync()
{
    var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/authorize",
        Items =
        {
            { "scheme", "oidc" },
            { "returnUrl", "/authorize" }
        }
    };
    return HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationProperties);
}
```

I've been in TypeScript Land the last few years, so I would like to return something like `IActionResult | Task`, or perhaps `Task<IActionResult> | Task`, but I don't think this is possible in C#.

The code I'm using is a hack. It usually works, but sometimes (usually the first time), it throws an error

> {"stateMachine":{"<>1__state":3,"<>t__builder":{

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604749/error-statemachine1-state-2-t-builder-when-run-project-netco) says it is likely happening because I'm not awaiting something that should be awaited. I can await the `ChallengeAsync` and return a `Task`, but that messes up the types in the `Authorize` function in a way I can't untangle.

Comment: you are returning an unawaited Task from an async method -- of course it's going to serialize that way. What would you expect otherwise? Take the `async` off of `ChallengeAsync` so it looks like this: `public Task<dynamic> ChallengeAsync()`. Then make sure the caller awaits on it.

Comment: Can you not return a `ChallengeResult` instead? It's not the intention of the `ChallengeAsync` method that it's returned `Task` is to be passed back to the browser/client.

Comment: In C# there is nothing like the Typescript union types. You can use Task.FromResult to return an already completed task in the redirect case.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever! It seems this piece of information that was trivial to you is invaluable to me. This is what happens when you send a front end person to do a full stack's job. 

Answer (score 1):

I've just bumped into this issue but I resolved it using the base controllers' `Challenge` action helpers.

```cs
public IActionResult Authorize()
{
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return Redirect("/authorize");
    }

    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = "/authorize",
        Items =
        {
            { "scheme", "oidc" },
            { "returnUrl", "/authorize" }
        }
    }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
}
```